# Mail chimp sending all feeds every time to subscribers

Tags: wordpress, rss, mailchimp

I am using mailchimp integration with wordpress. I am looking for solution like mailchimp should send email to all subscribers when I add new post to my wordpress site.

I am using generic wordpress RSS feed to let mailchimp about new post added but unfortunately mailchimp is sending all posts to subscribers every time, I just want to send new added post only.

Answer (score 0):

In the back-end of your website Update **Settings > Reading > Syndication feeds show the most recent to 1** and it'll show only 1 recent post